# Infinity edge interaction?

Tags: league-of-legends

The Infinity Edge states that "critical strike bonus damage is increased by 50%".

And the critical hit mechanic states that it does 200% base damage.

So on a crit, does it do 300% as that's an additional 50% of the 200%, or does it do 250% (200% + 50%) ?

Answer (score 6):

Critical strike bonus damage is a stat and Infinity Edge simply adds 50% to this stat.

This means that you will have a total of 250% Critical strike damage with the item.

Comment: I think he is asking how it interacts with other crit damage, so if I took +30% crit damage ruins, would infinity edge add 50% crit damage onto that 30% to make 200% + 30% + 50% = 280% crit damage?

Comment: @KeaganDalley Yes you'd get 280% crit damage. As I said critical damage is a stat. Every extra percent is added additively, not multiplicatively.